# JavaScript Invoking String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running into a string violation error with my ORM that is related to the value being passed to the authenticationToken property in my method. Is this due to the fact that I'm returning the method? The value I am looking to pass is `buf.toString('hex')`.

```
.post(function(req, res, organization){

        function token() {
            return crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf){
                buf.toString('hex');
            });
        };

        models.Member.create({
            organizationId: req.body.organizationId,
            memberEmail: req.body.addMember,
        }).then(function(){

            return models.User.create({
                email: req.body.addMember,
                authenticationToken: token()
            });
        }).then(function(){
            console.log("Success");
            res.redirect('/app/settings/add-users');
        })  
    });
```

Here is my error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: string violation: authenticationToken cannot be an array or an object
```

Comment: So what is `token().buf`?

Comment: @zerkms sorry I updated it. It should just be `token()`

Comment: So `token()` returns an object, hence you get an exception. Have you checked the documentation for `crypto.randomBytes`?

Comment: got it. Makes sense. What would be the method I would use on `token()` to return the randomly generated string that is set to the `buf` parameter?

Comment: It would be `crypto.randomBytes`

Comment: Is this, nodejs [`randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback)or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a missing `return` keyword?  The anonymous function in your call to `crypto.randomBytes` doesn't return anything.

Comment: And does it need to return anything? What makes you thinking so?

Comment: after [reading the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) I would say so. In this case it might be better to simply set the `token` property to `crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')` directly since it doesn't appear to have to happen asynchronously.

Comment: Simple enough fix. Big oversight by me. Thanks Eric Phillips and @zerkms